# The product is not available for purchase" after updating RevenueCat

Tags: react-native, google-play-console, revenuecat, android-inapp-purchase, google-play-billing

I'm currently facing an issue after updating RevenueCat in my React Native app in order to migrate to Google Play Billing Library 5. When I test in both closed and internal testing, I receive an error "The product is not available for purchase."

Everything was working perfectly fine before I updated RevenueCat. I'm now wondering whether the problem lies in my code or if it's related to my subscriptions on the Google Play Console

Your insights and experiences would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!